# Loop JSON.stringify and Display it on the SELECT

Tags: jquery, json

```
var new_result = JSON.stringify(result);
// this is the info of new_result
{
    "1":"Motor-boats : Motor-yachts > 50'",
    "2":"Motor-boats : Super-yachts > 100'",
    "3":"Motor-boats : Mega-yachts > 150'"
}

//loop if how many key value pair there is
$('#vessel_sub_category_id').append($('<option>', { value: 1, text: "Motor-boats : Motor-yachts > 50'" }));
```

actually sir I found this code.. when I isolate this it works but when I put it on ajax post success it doesn't work I don't know why..

this code is inside the ajax post.

```
  var obj = JSON.stringify(result);
  $.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
  alert( key + ": " + value );
  });
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question/the problem?

Comment: if you want to loop data object why are you converting to string?

Comment: @charlietfl the jQuery $.each function doesn't work in function success inside the ajax post..  but when I isolate the $.each function and put a dummy values it works.. I don't know what is the problem.. or maybe it doesn't work inside the ajax post?

Comment: loop over `result` object not a json string representation of it

Comment: uhm what do you mean sir? the $.each() function there will get the key value pair.. but it doesn't work inside the jquery ajax post success function.. I try isolating the code $.each() and it works.

Comment: what does `alert(typeof result)` show? If it is `'string'` you need `JSON.parse` not `stringify`. If it is `'object'` you just pass result to `each`

Comment: yeah you are right sir.. I dont need to stringify.. I just need to pass the result directly to $.each() function.. my bad sir.. ty for the help... that give me a heart attack though.... thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to work it out the other way around, you need to parse JSON instead of stringify and then use it as a JS object:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(result);
$.each(obj, function(key, value) {
    alert(key + ": " + value);
});
```